# Remove KDE Plasma widgets in Ubuntu Studio 21.04

Tags: kde, widgets

I'm completely new to Linux. I had no choice but to install a Linux distro to my desktop (I couldn't run my old Windows XP hard drive on my new [second hand bits] Frankenstein) computer, so I googled the best distros for audio recording and Ubuntu Studio was at the top of the list. I have, as expected, several issues to sort out but for now, the most annoying is that I tried putting a widget on desktop to have quick access to other drives. A box landed on my screen and now I can't get rid of it. I tried by going to widgets again, all I succeeded in doing was dropping the same widget onto my desktop twice more. Right click on the widget does nothing at all and Enter Edit Mode turns up grey and won't allow me to click on it. Please help!

Comment: What's worse is the Help Center seems to be all wrong! As if it was written for a completely different setup of "KDE Plasma." It says to look for things in places that are nowhere to be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm starting to learn how to search problems for solutions (it's in the phrasing). Apparently this is a common problem in less recent versions of KDE if your machine is not online and you don't get updates. In Konsole (terminal)...[image] Problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the desktop and enter edit mode.

[image: right click]

Now hover on the widget, and you would find the remove (bin) button.

[image: kde edit mode]

Comment: Thanks man, appreciated. However, oddly enough, Enter Edit Mode is grey and won't let me click on it. The machine is not online either, so I can't even show you a screen shot.

Comment: @JeromeParli Sorry I have no clue how that could have happened. Please edit your question with this information (Enter Edit Mode is grey).

Comment: Thanks again, your solution worked perfectly, once I sorted the Enter Edit Mode issue.